# How can I retrieve a value in jquery with a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, recursion, button

I have the following code:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="new_tax_button_post_tag"]').click(function(){
        value = $('input[name="post_tag"]').val();
        $("#fieldID3").val(value); 
    });
});
```

and I want it change:

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" id="fieldID3" name="changeme"value="n/a">
```

The problem is that the click itself is what creates the value, so I have to click the button twice to get the desired results. The first click creates the value. The second click sets the value in the field. 
How do I make it so that it does it in one click?
It's like which came first the chicken or the egg.....

Comment: post you html code also

Comment: Please provide the complete code or make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

I write jquery on the basis of ID of button and textbox,
and also remove value from following input field,

```
<input type="text" id="fieldID3" name="changeme">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_tax_button_post_tag").click(function(){
        value = $("#post_tag").val();
        $("#fieldID3").val(value); 
    });
});
```

I hope this useful for you.